# Wrapper for blas in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, blas

**Response to comments**

Several people pointed out that I am trying to violate the fortran standard. This is not the case, I would like to have perfectly portable and standard-compliant code. Below is my naive way to approach it. Obviously it does not work. Thus, I do not know the solution, but I am quite confident about the desired functionality. The way to achieve this functionality is not essential. I am not bound by `fortran`, although this is preferable.

### Original post

I discovered recently that `ZGEMM` from the `BLAS` library gives sub-optimal performance for complex-real matrix multiplication. Replacing 1 complex-complex `ZGEMM` with two calls to `DGEMM` I was able to cut the run time by 3 times (*not by 1.5 as naive expectation would be*)!

```
module Mmatmul
contains
  subroutine zd_matmul_module(n,a,b,c,T1,T2)
    integer,intent(in)::n
    double complex,intent(in)::a(:,:)
    double complex,intent(out)::c(:,:)
    double precision::T1(:,:),T2(:,:),b(:,:)

    ! copy real part 
    call dcopy (n*n, a, 2, T1, 1)
    call dgemm ('N', 'N', n, n, n, 1.0D0, T1, n, B, n, 0.0D0, T2, n)
    ! put result on hold
    call dcopy (n*n, T2, 1, C, 1)

    ! copy imaginary part
    T1=dimag(a)
    call dgemm ('N', 'N', n, n, n, 1.0D0, T1, n, B, n, 0.0D0, T2, n)
    call dcopy (n*n, C, 1, T1, 1)

    ! put real and imaginary parts in place
    C=DCMPLX(T1,T2)
  end subroutine zd_matmul_module
end module Mmatmul
```

This subroutine is very transparent, however, it is **less flexible** than `BLAS` subroutines. For instance, two temporary matrices `T1` and `T2` are required to have the right type and shape. This is inconvenient. Consider for instance a situation, where I need two perform 3 complex-double multiplications with the result being a rank-2, rank-3, and rank-4 matrix. It means writing 3 dedicated subroutines, and having 6 different temporary matrices!

*On the other hand, subroutines in the `BLAS` do not care about the type and shape of its arguments provided the passed arrays have the right size.* This is a very desirable property to me.

Therefore, I would like to write a wrapper to BLAS subroutines in fortran such that it does not make type and shape checks, exactly how it is done in `BLAS`. I was thinking of using an *external* subroutine, which would help me to *circumvent the type and the rank fortran checks*. I consciously want to do it, because it is really a **bottleneck of my code**.

I came up with this implementation

```
subroutine zd_matmul_external(n,a,b,c,T1,T2)
integer,intent(in)::n
double precision,intent(in)::a(*)
double precision,intent(out)::c(*)
double precision::T1(*),T2(*),b(*)

call dcopy (n*n, a(1), 2, T1, 1)
call dgemm ('N', 'N', n, n, n, 1.0D0, T1, n, B, n, 0.0D0, T2, n)
call dcopy (n*n, T2, 1, C(1), 2)

call dcopy (n*n, a(2), 2, T1, 1)
call dgemm ('N', 'N', n, n, n, 1.0D0, T1, n, B, n, 0.0D0, T2, n)
call dcopy (n*n, T2, 1, C(2), 2)
end subroutine zd_matmul_external
```

It compiles, but gives a run-time error indicating a *memory problem*. Since it compiles, and it structure is similar to the `BLAS` implementation I believe it is not syntactically wrong. But what is the problem?

For completeness, this is the main program

```
 program Psmall
  use Mmatmul
  integer, allocatable::seed(:)
  integer:: sz,n
  double complex, allocatable :: AZ(:,:), BZ(:,:)
  double complex, allocatable :: CZ1(:,:), CZ2(:,:), CZ3(:,:)
  double precision, allocatable :: BD(:,:), AR(:,:), AI(:,:)

  external :: zd_matmul_external
  
  call  random_seed(size = sz)  ! Finds the size sz of the seed
  allocate (seed(sz))
  open ( unit=1, file='/dev/urandom', access='stream', form='UNFORMATTED')
  read (1) seed
  close (1)

  ! -- prepare random arrays --
  n= 500
  allocate(AR(n,n),AI(n,n),BD(n,n),AZ(n,n),BZ(n,n),CZ1(n,n),CZ2(n,n),CZ3(n,n))
  call random_number(AR)
  call random_number(AI)
  call random_number(BD)
  AZ=DCMPLX(AR,AI)
  BZ=DCMPLX(BD)
  
  ! -- fast, but inconvenient -- 
  call zd_matmul_module(n, AZ, BD, CZ1, AR, AI)

  ! Problematic next line
  call zd_matmul_external(n, AZ,BD,CZ2, AR, AI)

  CZ3 = matmul(AZ, BD) 

  print*,sqrt(sum(abs(cz1-cz3)**2)),sqrt(sum(abs(cz2-cz3)**2))
end program Psmall
```

I am using gfortran compiler (gcc version 5.3.0) @ macOS 10.13.5.

Comment: (1) You need to update your gfortran compiler.  5.3.0 is ancient. (2) which BLAS library are you using?  (3) And most importantly, uf you are purposely violating the rules of Fortran, I'm afraid we cannot help you.

Comment: @steve I am not violating any rules, this is the standard adopted in the well known BLAS library. The library is supported by almost all hardware vendors and has replicated many times as automatically compilable library.  All source codes for the library are available online demonstrating exactly this programing style.  I would like to write a fortran code in compliance with this library.

Comment: @steve To answer the first 2 questions: 1) this version might well be old, but this is not only my decision. Moreover it supports well the 2003 standard. 2) I am currently using `BLAS` from the `-framework Accelerate` but the `MKL` is the target.

Comment: Gfortran 5 certainly does not support the complete Fortran 2003 standard and there are many known bugs in certain parts it does support.

Comment: You are doing *"external subroutine, which would help me to circumvent the type and the rank fortran checks."*. That is your purposeful violation of Fortran rules.

Comment: @VladimirF Ok, may well be, but this is not the point here. The code above should work even with f90 standard.

Comment: @VladimirF But every blas subroutine does exactly this. http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/index.html

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @VladimirF Maybe I do not know something, but I have been passing rank-3 and rank-4 tensors to BLAS since ages. And complex to real works perfectly in the first example above. Or do you mean to say that BLAS functionality cannot in principle be implemented in fortran? But why they provide fortran listing on the netlib?

Comment: The fact that you can get away with something does not mean it is allowed. You are supposed to follow the rules of the Fortran standard when calling the BLAS routines. And face the consequences if you don't.

Comment: The problem is you are passing a complex type to a real type. With assumed size arrays it's horrible but you are allowed to tell lies about the rank of the arrays - that how BLAS gets away with that. Also second the motion to update the compiler

Comment: I don't think you need a C wrapper (might run into the same conformity problems) but you could have a look at the standard functions `REAL` and `AIMAG`

Comment: Did you see the answer from Ian Bush that uses the `real` and `aimag`?

Comment: @albert What should I see there, he rigidly fixes ranks? Just to resolve the confusion. Rank of the tensor `T1(:,:,:)`is 3 and of `T2(:,:,:,:,:)` is 5. In the answer below the word rank is used to denote dimensions, i.e., `T3(n,m)` here `n` and `m` are the dimensions.

Comment: In your question you don't speak of different ranks at all, but when you would give an example of a call with `T1` and `T2` with different ranks.. (probably you will have something like `... ,T1,T2(:,:,:,1,1) ...` in your call.

Comment: @albert Well, one can always emphasize certain things even more, but see the passage in the OP  around the sentence "Consider for instance a situation, where I need two perform 3 complex-double multiplications with the result being a rank-2, rank-3, and rank-4 matrix. "

Comment: Though I haven't followed the Q/As, isn't it another approach to use rank remapping of array pointers (e.g. to locally make an array view with different ranks), and possibly with `c_f_pointer()` to change real vs complex views (as an alternative to "external + different type arguments" approach, as often used in BLAS routines)?

Comment: @royvib Actually I tried to go this direction myself but I lack some knowledge about the pointers to complete this idea. Can you please post your idea as an answer. I would really learn a lot from it.

Comment: @roygvib This was the suggestion of many people. I will certainly try to convince my colleagues to update. Fully agree!

Comment: @yarchik I guess there may be some previous Q/As very close to the above topic on this site, but not sure which  is a good one atm... It may also be useful to ask related questions on [fortran-lang](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/) in addition to this site)

Comment: One reason that you may want to move to newer gfortran is that the gfortran volunteers have worked to improve `MATMUL`, so you may be able to leverage that work.  In addition, you can use the `-fexternal-blas` option, which causes gfortran to generate a call to `zgemm` for you.   This will then used whatever BLAS optimized library you have.  It hides the details.  Finally, calling a routine with a type mismatch between an actual and dummy argument has never been standard conforming Fortran.  This restriction goes back to the FORTRAN 66 standard.

Comment: @steve this is very computationally intensive project, already `zgemm` is too slow for me. I have more reader friendly implementations in Mathematica and python. They work perfectly, are very beautiful to read, but they hit the wall at some point. Therefore I moved to fortran. This piece of code is really the bottleneck, both in cpu time and having to keep so many temporary arrays.

Comment: As your well-posed desired functionality violates restrictions of the Fortran standard dating back 70 or so years, I suspect you're in processor-dependent behavior category.  BTW, you attempt at avoiding temporaries is not working, and may in fact make things worse.  `gfortran -Warray-temporaries your_files.f90 |& grep -i Creating | wc -l` gives 25.

Comment: @steve Thanks for checking. I suspect this is because of the faulty external routine. I do not insist on fortran as I write in the 1st paragraph. If this is not possible, then I am ready to accept it and move on.  However, I am puzzled by the fact that BLAS achieves exactly this functionality and *is* programmed in fortran (generic version). How would you explain this?

Comment: Type mismatch has never been allowed by the Fortran standards.  This, however, never stopped a programmer from trying to use this idiom nor did it stop Fortran compiler vendors from allowing it.  Commercial compilers, of course, had a monetary reason to allow it (i.e., the customer is always right).  gfortran is not a commercial compiler; so now, if it detects the mismatch, gfortran will issue an error (or warning).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like the below, which blocks the multiply into managebale chunks. It is standard conformant, shows a marked increase in speed over openblas (on my laptop) and for large matrices uses markedly less memory than the suggested implementation. Only  written for and tested on single thread, I leave parallelisation as an exercise. You can also probably get better performance by tuning the buffer size.

Code:

```
Module blas_interfaces_module

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64

  Implicit None ( Type, External )

  Interface

     Subroutine dgemm( transa, transb, m, n, k, alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, beta, c, ldc )
       Import wp
       Implicit None ( Type, External )
       Character                 , Intent( In    ) :: transa
       Character                 , Intent( In    ) :: transb
       Integer                   , Intent( In    ) :: m
       Integer                   , Intent( In    ) :: n
       Integer                   , Intent( In    ) :: k
       Real( wp )                , Intent( In    ) :: alpha
       Real( wp ), Dimension( * ), Intent( In    ) :: a
       Integer                   , Intent( In    ) :: lda
       Real( wp ), Dimension( * ), Intent( In    ) :: b
       Integer                   , Intent( In    ) :: ldb
       Real( wp )                , Intent( In    ) :: beta
       Real( wp ), Dimension( * ), Intent(   Out ) :: c
       Integer                   , Intent( In    ) :: ldc
     End Subroutine dgemm

       Subroutine zgemm( transa, transb, m, n, k, alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, beta, c, ldc )
       Import wp
       Implicit None ( Type, External )
       Character                    , Intent( In    ) :: transa
       Character                    , Intent( In    ) :: transb
       Integer                      , Intent( In    ) :: m
       Integer                      , Intent( In    ) :: n
       Integer                      , Intent( In    ) :: k
       Complex( wp )                , Intent( In    ) :: alpha
       Complex( wp ), Dimension( * ), Intent( In    ) :: a
       Integer                      , Intent( In    ) :: lda
       Complex( wp ), Dimension( * ), Intent( In    ) :: b
       Integer                      , Intent( In    ) :: ldb
       Complex( wp )                , Intent( In    ) :: beta
       Complex( wp ), Dimension( * ), Intent(   Out ) :: c
       Integer                      , Intent( In    ) :: ldc
     End Subroutine zgemm

  End Interface

  Public :: dgemm
  Public :: zgemm

  Private
  
End Module blas_interfaces_module

Module mm_complex_real_module

  Implicit None ( Type, External )

  Public :: mm_complex_real

  Private
  
Contains

  Subroutine mm_complex_real( n, a, b, c )

    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64

    Use blas_interfaces_module, Only : dgemm
    
    Implicit None ( Type, External )

    Integer                             , Intent( In    ) :: n
    Complex( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ), Intent( In    ) :: a
    Real   ( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ), Intent( In    ) :: b
    Complex( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ), Intent(   Out ) :: c
    
    Integer, Parameter :: n_buff_max = 2048

    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: a_real, a_imag
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: c_real, c_imag

    Integer :: i_start, j_start, k_start
    Integer :: i_end  , j_end  , k_end
    Integer :: i_len  , j_len  , k_len
    Integer :: n_buff
    Integer :: i, j, k

    n_buff = Min( n_buff_max, n )
    Allocate( a_real( 1:n_buff, 1:n_buff ) )
    Allocate( a_imag( 1:n_buff, 1:n_buff ) )
    Allocate( c_real( 1:n_buff, 1:n_buff ) )
    Allocate( c_imag( 1:n_buff, 1:n_buff ) )

    c = 0.0_wp
    
    j_start = 1
    Do While( j_start < n )

       j_end = Min( j_start + n_buff - 1, n )
       j_len = j_end - j_start + 1

       i_start = 1
       Do While( i_start < n )
          
          i_end = Min( i_start + n_buff - 1, n )
          i_len = i_end - i_start + 1

          Do j = 1, j_len
             Do i = 1, i_len
                a_real( i, j ) = Real ( a( i + i_start - 1, j + j_start - 1 ), wp )
                a_imag( i, j ) = Aimag( a( i + i_start - 1, j + j_start - 1 )     )
             End Do
          End Do

          k_start = 1
          Do While( k_start < n )
             
             k_end = Min( k_start + n_buff - 1, n )
             k_len = k_end - k_start + 1
          
             Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', i_len, k_len, j_len, 1.0_wp, a_real                    , Size( a_real, Dim = 1 ), &
                                                                b     ( j_start, k_start ), Size( b     , Dim = 1 ), &
                                                        0.0_wp, c_real                    , Size( c_real, Dim = 1 ) )
             Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', i_len, k_len, j_len, 1.0_wp, a_imag                    , Size( a_imag, Dim = 1 ), &
                                                                b     ( j_start, k_start ), Size( b     , Dim = 1 ), &
                                                        0.0_wp, c_imag                    , Size( c_imag, Dim = 1 ) )

             Do k = k_start, k_end
                Do i = i_start, i_end
                   c( i, k ) = c( i, k ) + &
                        Cmplx( c_real( i - i_start + 1, k - k_start + 1 ), &
                               c_imag( i - i_start + 1, k - k_start + 1 ), Kind = wp )
                End Do
             End Do

             k_start = k_start + n_buff
          End Do
             
          i_start = i_start + n_buff
       End Do

       j_start = j_start + n_buff
    End Do

  End Subroutine mm_complex_real
  
End Module mm_complex_real_module

Program testit

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64, li => int64, stdout => output_unit

  Use mm_complex_real_module, Only : mm_complex_real
  Use blas_interfaces_module, Only : dgemm, zgemm

  Implicit None ( Type, External )

  Complex( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: a
  Complex( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: c_ref, c_blas, c_mine
  Complex( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: b_complex

  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: b
  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: a_real, a_imag

  Real( wp ) :: t_ref, t_blas, t_mine
  
  Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate
  
  Integer :: n

  Do n = 500, 8000, 500

     Allocate( a     ( 1:n, 1:n ) )
     Allocate( b     ( 1:n, 1:n ) )
     Allocate( c_ref ( 1:n, 1:n ) )
     Allocate( c_blas( 1:n, 1:n ) )
     Allocate( c_mine( 1:n, 1:n ) )

     Allocate( a_real( 1:n, 1:n ) )
     Allocate( a_imag( 1:n, 1:n ) )
     Call Random_number( a_real )
     Call Random_number( a_imag )
     a = Cmplx( a_real, a_imag, Kind = wp )
     Deallocate( a_imag )
     Deallocate( a_real )

     Call Random_number( b )

     Call system_clock( start, rate )
     c_ref = Matmul( a, b )
     Call system_clock( finish, rate )
     t_ref = Real( finish - start, Kind = Kind( t_ref )  ) / rate

     Allocate( b_complex( 1:n, 1:n ) )
     Call system_clock( start, rate )
     b_complex = b
     Call zgemm( 'N', 'N', n, n, n, ( 1.0_wp, 0.0_wp ), a        , Size( a        , Dim = 1 ), &
                                                        b_complex, Size( b_complex, Dim = 1 ), &
                                    ( 0.0_wp, 0.0_wp ), c_blas   , Size( c_blas   , Dim = 1 ) )
     Call system_clock( finish, rate )
     t_blas = Real( finish - start, Kind = Kind( t_ref )  ) / rate
     Deallocate( b_complex )

     Call system_clock( start, rate )
     Call mm_complex_real( n, a, b, c_mine )
     Call system_clock( finish, rate )
     t_mine = Real( finish - start, Kind = Kind( t_ref )  ) / rate

     Write( stdout, '( a, t12, "Rank = ", i5, t30, "Time = ", f9.4 )' ) 'Reference', n, t_ref
     Write( stdout, '( a, t12, "Rank = ", i5, t30, "Time = ", f9.4, t50, "Error = ", g20.10 )' ) &
          'BLAS', n, t_blas, Maxval( Abs( c_ref - c_blas ) )
     Write( stdout, '( a, t12, "Rank = ", i5, t30, "Time = ", f9.4, t50, "Error = ", g20.10 )' ) &
          'Mine', n, t_mine, Maxval( Abs( c_ref - c_mine ) )
     Write( stdout, * )

     Deallocate( c_mine )
     Deallocate( c_blas )
     Deallocate( c_ref  )
     Deallocate( b      )
     Deallocate( a      )
     
  End Do
  
End Program testit
```

Testing on small matrices with debugging flags, and compiler version:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -std=f2018 -fcheck=all -finit-real=snan -fexternal-blas -Wuse-without-only   mm.f90 -g -lopenblas
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
Reference  Rank =   500      Time =    0.0317
BLAS       Rank =   500      Time =    0.0244    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =   500      Time =    0.0221    Error =     0.2049518614E-12

Reference  Rank =  1000      Time =    0.1776
BLAS       Rank =  1000      Time =    0.1810    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  1000      Time =    0.1260    Error =     0.3215549355E-12

Reference  Rank =  1500      Time =    0.5452
BLAS       Rank =  1500      Time =    0.5370    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  1500      Time =    0.3571    Error =     0.4687428402E-12

Reference  Rank =  2000      Time =    1.1895
BLAS       Rank =  2000      Time =    1.1421    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  2000      Time =    0.7319    Error =     0.5084229946E-12

Reference  Rank =  2500      Time =    2.1990
BLAS       Rank =  2500      Time =    2.1870    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  2500      Time =    1.6239    Error =     0.7279509461E-12

Reference  Rank =  3000      Time =    4.3954
BLAS       Rank =  3000      Time =    4.0730    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  3000      Time =    2.6654    Error =     0.8276526716E-12

Reference  Rank =  3500      Time =    6.1562
BLAS       Rank =  3500      Time =    6.4210    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  3500      Time =    4.5101    Error =     0.1016845989E-11

Reference  Rank =  4000      Time =    9.4788
BLAS       Rank =  4000      Time =    9.7646    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  4000      Time =    6.1978    Error =     0.1023181539E-11

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```

Testing on large matrices with compiler optimisation turned on:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -std=f2018 -O3 -fexternal-blas  -Wuse-without-only   mm.f90 -lopenblas
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
Reference  Rank =   500      Time =    0.0324
BLAS       Rank =   500      Time =    0.0244    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =   500      Time =    0.0174    Error =     0.1819877365E-12

Reference  Rank =  1000      Time =    0.1849
BLAS       Rank =  1000      Time =    0.1741    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  1000      Time =    0.1075    Error =     0.3215549355E-12

Reference  Rank =  1500      Time =    0.5684
BLAS       Rank =  1500      Time =    0.5422    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  1500      Time =    0.3051    Error =     0.4582862942E-12

Reference  Rank =  2000      Time =    1.1869
BLAS       Rank =  2000      Time =    1.1340    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  2000      Time =    0.6584    Error =     0.5796914040E-12

Reference  Rank =  2500      Time =    2.1756
BLAS       Rank =  2500      Time =    2.2456    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  2500      Time =    1.5541    Error =     0.7279509461E-12

Reference  Rank =  3000      Time =    4.3817
BLAS       Rank =  3000      Time =    4.1084    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  3000      Time =    2.6164    Error =     0.8198074455E-12

Reference  Rank =  3500      Time =    6.0470
BLAS       Rank =  3500      Time =    6.2369    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  3500      Time =    4.0864    Error =     0.9713407673E-12

Reference  Rank =  4000      Time =    9.6197
BLAS       Rank =  4000      Time =    9.5614    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  4000      Time =    6.0322    Error =     0.1048140855E-11

Reference  Rank =  4500      Time =   13.2843
BLAS       Rank =  4500      Time =   13.9924    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  4500      Time =    8.5252    Error =     0.1325804964E-11

Reference  Rank =  5000      Time =   19.0425
BLAS       Rank =  5000      Time =   18.5975    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  5000      Time =   11.7193    Error =     0.1525268984E-11

Reference  Rank =  5500      Time =   25.1735
BLAS       Rank =  5500      Time =   25.2269    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  5500      Time =   15.5540    Error =     0.1607774678E-11

Reference  Rank =  6000      Time =   32.5070
BLAS       Rank =  6000      Time =   35.5822    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  6000      Time =   20.9217    Error =     0.1775845175E-11

Reference  Rank =  6500      Time =   42.5040
BLAS       Rank =  6500      Time =   41.4937    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  6500      Time =   25.5950    Error =     0.1942681535E-11

Reference  Rank =  7000      Time =   51.9414
BLAS       Rank =  7000      Time =   52.3054    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  7000      Time =   31.4987    Error =     0.2033691978E-11

Reference  Rank =  7500      Time =   63.9316
BLAS       Rank =  7500      Time =   63.9044    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  7500      Time =   38.7648    Error =     0.2250884549E-11

Reference  Rank =  8000      Time =   77.2484
BLAS       Rank =  8000      Time =   78.0691    Error =      0.000000000    
Mine       Rank =  8000      Time =   46.3565    Error =     0.2273736754E-11

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```

Comment: This is a possible solution. However, there several issues with it: 1) Declarations like `Complex( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ), Intent( In    ) :: a` means data copy when a matrix passed to the subroutine. 2) Allocation of space in the subroutine is undesirable for performance reasons (does not play a role for big matrices though). 3) No flexibility in ranks of arguments (really serious problem for me). In other words, you propose a super rigid approach meaning that one needs countless such routines for all cases of life.

Comment: "Declarations like Complex( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ), Intent( In    ) :: a means data copy when a matrix passed to the subroutine" Why do you keep saying this? No it doesn't.

Comment: Well you can always pass pre-allocated temporaries if you so wish - I prefer to keep my code tidy and maintainable by minimising the time and space that variables are in scope

Comment: If you need to adjust the ranks make the dummy arguments something like ( 1:n, * ) and change the use of the Size intrinsic appropriately, or alternatively look at rank remapping via pointers

Comment: I have made some tests long time ago. Maybe something has changed in new compilers, I would not bet on that.  Pre-allocated temporaries are also fine. But fixed ranks defeat the purpose of the whole discussion. I already mention in the OP. I would like to be able to pass sometimes a rank-2 object `B2(:,:)`, sometimes  rank-3 `B3(:,:,:)`, sometimes `B4(:,:,:,:)` and not allocate each time different temporaries. Moreover, you use loops to copy the data. This works only for rank-2.

Comment: @jack Of course,  `dgemm` need contiguous arrays! That's the point of the whole discussion.